# Extract only Base64 hash from the string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having the base64 image which has stored in the database like below.

```
<p>gtbtrhtrh</p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" data-filename="] 4672 (1).jpg" style="width: 211px;"><p><br></p>
```

I want to extract only the base64 hash using javascript or angularjs.
Please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried  $scope.image = angular.element(scontent).find('img:eq(1)');

Comment: Let me know how to extract only the img tag from there using angularjs